# session gets cleared once method finish

Tags: asp.net, web-services, session

I have two methods in my `webservice.cs`  page like below.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public void checkEmployee(string emailId, string password)
        {
            List<Employee> ListEmp = new List<Employee>();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rushDB"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees where Email='" + emailId + "' AND Password='" + password + "'", con);
                string personName = null;
                string personEmail = null;
                string personDeptName = null;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Employee empChild = new Employee();

                        empChild.ID = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["ID"]);
                        empChild.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                        empChild.Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                        empChild.Password = rdr["Password"].ToString();
                        empChild.DepartName = rdr["DepartName"].ToString();

                        personName = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                        personEmail = rdr["Email"].ToString();
                        personDeptName = rdr["DepartName"].ToString();

                        ListEmp.Add(empChild);
                    }
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["NamePerson"] = personName;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["EmailPerson"] = personEmail;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["DepartPerson"] = personDeptName;
                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(ListEmp));
                }
            }
        }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public void GetCurrentData()
        {
            Employee ListEmp = new Employee();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["NamePerson"] != null)
                ListEmp.Name = HttpContext.Current.Session["NamePerson"].ToString();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["EmailPerson"] != null)
                ListEmp.Email = HttpContext.Current.Session["EmailPerson"].ToString();
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["DepartPerson"] != null)
                ListEmp.DepartName = HttpContext.Current.Session["DepartPerson"].ToString();

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(ListEmp));
        }
```

My issue is that the session created in checkEmployee gets vanished after that method checkEmployee finishes its execution.

I want to retrieve the session values in GetCurrentData but i am unable to do so. Any solution would help me. i have googled it but that didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *cookie-jar* to be able to retain session-state on Web Services. Depending on how you're consuming the service it can get **quite** complicated if you haven't done it before...

Have at look at the following articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322436/RestSessionState

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188749/WCF-Sessions-Brief-Introduction

Comment: I dont know this is helpful or not but, my problem was not solved

Comment: @Rush.2707 - when dealing with webpages, the browser helps retain the session-state by using session cookies. with web services you don't have that luxury. Instead you need to use a method to login which returns a token (like a cookie). Now that you have the token you can keep sending it back with each subsequent request so that the server can identify you.